# Xpages document feild starting with '$' sign does not allows to save document in a database.ERROR:[TypeError] NotesDocument.save(boolean) null

Tags: runtime-error, xpages

I am having database in which my Xpage contains a very simple code to create a document.

```
var d:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
d.replaceItemValue("$test","dollar");
d.save(false);
```

Above code throws an error

```
 [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.save(boolean) null
```

If I remove $ sign it works fine in this database,So I found that it is have some problem with $ Sign.

Notes version 9.

On the other hand if I try to use same code in other database, above code works fine.

I am just wondering that, Is there any settings for the database to restrict some kind signs or any thing else.

I searched on google I also find that some developers too got the same issue, but in my case only a perticular database is having this problem.

This problem was not there from begining recently I found this problem with this database,So there are lots of fields which I already used with '$'. This issue is only on my local server, There no problem on the live server.

I am actually worried that, What if I will get the same problem in futher on the live server. In that case I have change all the fields where I have used '$' sign.

Hope I am clear with the question.

Any kind of solution will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: I seems to be a problem since version 9. I have tested your code using domino server 8.5.3 without any problems.

Comment: yes I have also tested this 8.5 it works well, My problem is this happens only in that perticular database and only on my machine,when I have tested this other database on the same server there also it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running a copy style compact (-c option) on the database. Also, make sure the database is using the latest ODS version (see: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/inst_dominoondiskstructure_t.html)

I have run into similar issues where only one particular database is causing an issue. Running a copy style compact usually resolves these kinds of issues.